# why cursor.execute with pymysql always get nonetype error

Tags: python, cursor, pymysql

I was trying to update records with cursor.execute in the database but it always return NoneType not iterable error, so i decided to test with something simple like 'select curtime()' and it gives the same error.

```
cnx=pymysql.connect(user=user,password=pw,
                   host=127.0.0.1,port=3306,db=test,autocommit=True)
cursor=cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute('Select curtime()')
```

i get 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Edit:
I see what you mean by needing the full traceback, i came back home and the problem went away

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 51, in close
while self.nextset():
```

with this error i found from other articles its because my earlier real sql statement string **cursor.execute(longsqlstatement)** is very long and when i try to close the connection and cursor, it causes that error. and in my curtime() test, because my earlier cursor havent finish executing it causes the NoneType error too. So my question is how do i then know all the sql statement has ran successfully and i can close the connection?

Comment: Not from that code you don't. Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an answer so decided to break the long multistatement string
        successitem=0
    faileditem=0

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
executeitems=statement.split(';')
for item in executeitems:
    item=item.strip()
    if item!='':
        try:
            cursor.execute(item)
            result=cursor.rowcount
            if result>-1:
                #print('Successful:',item)
                successitem=successitem+1
        except:
            faileditem=faileditem+1
            print('--FAIL TO UPDATE:', item)

cnx.commit()
print('successfully commited items:',successitem)
print('failed items:',faileditem)

cnx.close()
```